"npm run dev script not found even though it is there in package.json"
Despite correctly defining the "dev" script in the package.json file for a Vite project, running npm run dev results in an error indicating that the script is missing.
I verified the package.json file, checked for typos, ensured the npm version is up to date, tried reinstalling node modules, and attempted running the command npm run dev.
Following is the package.json file:
{
  "name": "grapes-detection-system",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint. --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "start": "node vite.js",
    "error": "vite build --mode development"
  }
  ,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.20.1",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.15",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint": "^8.53.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.4",
    "vite": "^5.0.0"
  }
  
}

Following is the error I am receiving on VS Code terminal:
PS C:\Users\Sana-PC\Downloads\grape-detection-system-main-updated> npm install

up to date, audited 11 packages in 2s

3 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
PS C:\Users\Sana-PC\Downloads\grape-detection-system-main-updated> npm run dev
npm ERR! Missing script: "dev"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Sana-PC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-04-21T08_43_48_014Z-debug-0.log


Try it follow steps below:

Remove your node_modules folder
Run command npm i to install all packages again
After start your project with npm run dev

